# About func(const int&) and func(const int)

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

class Account {
public:
    static double GetCircumference(const double &dR) { return 2 * dR * 3.1415926; }
    static constexpr double cd = 3.0;
};

// constexpr double Account::cd;

int main()
{
    std::cout << Account::GetCircumference(Account::cd) << std::endl;
}
```

The code is wrong unless I remove the "//".
But if I only change (const double &dR) to (const double dR), it becomes ok too.
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11, this in-class declaration:

```
static constexpr double cd = 3.0;
```

is not a *definition* (... until C++17; after which `constexpr` static data members are implicitly inline).

This is a out-of-class definition:

```
constexpr double Account::cd;
```

A definition is is needed if `Account::cd` is [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20an%20object%20is%20odr,is%20made%20or%20its%20address), which it is if it is passed to:

```
double GetCircumference(const double &dR);
```

as its reference is taken.

> **[[basic.def.odr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#3)** Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. [...]

However, if it is passed to

```
double GetCircumference(const double dR);
```

it is not odr-used:

> **[[basic.def.odr]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#2)** An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause [expr]) or a subexpression thereof. A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used **unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression** ([expr.const]) **and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion** ([conv.lval]) **is immediately applied**.

and a definition is not required.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. And I also want to know what happens when I pass a constexpr int to a func(const int &)? Is there still an address in memory for a constexpr when it is "substituted"? @dfrib

Comment: @Mikato The answer above holds also for the case where we replace `double` by `int`: the rules for when a variable is not odr-used relates to a) whether it may appear in a constant expression, and b) whether [\[conv.lval\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.lval#2) applies such that the original object is not referenced (but rather an rvalue is produced). The requirement for a definition follows from [\[basic.def.odr\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#3); namely that any variable that is odr-used shall be defined. I've expanded the answer accordingly.